# org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.xmlvaluedisconnectedexception

Tags: java, spring, selenium, apache-poi

```
public boolean addSheet(String  sheetname){     

    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    try {
         workbook.createSheet(sheetname);   
         fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
         workbook.write(fileOut);
         fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Above is my excel reader
    1)excel.setCellData(sheetname, "city", 4, "losangeles");
    2)  excel.addSheet("dddd");
only 1 or 2 is working but not both it is throwing xmlvalued disconnected excepton error

Comment: What you want to do? Everytime you want to create a new sheet?

Comment: yes correct. i want to set a data in cell and create a new sheet..Both codes are working only if run separate but not simultaneously

Comment: Can you update the code? How are you calling the function?

Comment: i have created an excelreader.java where lot of methods like addsheet, setceeldata,readcell data wriiten. then i created an object of excel reader. and calling the methods as  i have mentioned

Comment: `workbook.createSheet(sheetname); ` where it is defined? Looks like it is closed before you are calling it.

Comment: anychanges need to be done in addsheet method

Comment: thanks. it got solved. i have to reopen again